# c# .net - windows application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a c# windows application created using .net 4.0 f/w created in windows 7 platform.

during the deployment in windows xp in another pc, I need a popup requesting user to download .net 3.5 f/w in windows xp to run the setup and If .net 4.0 is already installed ie., above windows xp os ie., (vista/win 7) it should install the setup normally.

I tried this by using prerequisite in build property, but it is installing .net 3.5 f/w without checking the f/w whether it is installed previously/not.

I need a popup first for requesting the user to download or not.

One more thing, the f/w download memory space occupied during the setup once he accepts to download, is his own local memory and must not occupy mine.

Comment: What are you asking? How to show a pop up in winforms?

Comment: I think he's talking about creating an installer, but the OP needs to clarify (amongst other things) what installer technology he's using, if any.  And what is "f/w"?!

Comment: I am using vs installer for setup and deployment. f/w means framework

Comment: my query is : i created the application using .net 4.0 in windows 7 os. When i install the application in windows xp which has inbuilt .net 3.5 framework, i need to show a link to the user for installing 4.0 framework during the setup of my application.is it clear. i tried using the prerequisite in setup property but i need to show a donwload link to the user to download .net 4.0 framework. please help!

Comment: The .NET 4 bootstrapper you include with the Prerequisites already knows how to check if it is installed and knows where to download from.  Stop helping.

Answer (score 1):

just use [VSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx)

This will allow you to manage the required Framework versions, in only a few clicks.

But what are you talking about with the memory ? Are you talking about the `Framework` installer that shouldnt occupy your programs memory ? If so, your program will not be running, because it requires the `framework` which will be in the process of being installed only.